# Using complex numbers in stem command in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two numpy arrays `a` (having integer values) and `b` (having complex numbers). Now when I use `stem(a,b)`, I get the following error:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:235: 
    ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary 
    part return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order) 
    Out[5]: <Container object of 3 artists>
```

Can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want it to do?  `stem` plot plots vertical lines at each horizontal `a`
location from the baseline to a height `b`. But here, `b` is a complex number -- you need it to be a real-valued quantity. Perhaps you want the absolute value, `np.abs(b)`? Or the real part, `np.real(b)`? Perhaps two stem plots, `stem(a, np.real(b)); stem(a, np.imag(b))`?

Comment: I want to plot "Complex Valued Exponential Sequence". So as part of my code, array a is having discrete sequences (0:10) and b is array of exponential sequence with complex numbers

Comment: But what do you want it to look like? A complex number has two real parts. How do you want them to appear?

Answer (score 0):

You only need the real part of the complex number for the stem plot.

```
x = np.arange(-64,64,1)
C = [cmath.exp(abs(i) * cmath.log(a3)) for i in x]
stem(x,real(C))
```

[Stem plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuPCO.jpg)